# Is there a problem with a (previously unawarded) tag badge?

Tags: discussion

I am wondering if there's a bug or I missed something obvious.

I recently - a few days back - got the (bronze) `self-study` tag badge (I've had a few others before).

I then noticed in my tag-list that I had more points in the histogram tag, but I have no badge for it. Currently [no users have that badge](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=bronze)* (two of my answers under this tag have over 70 points between them which is why it's so high for me).

Here's [my answers](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a805%20[histogram]) in order of votes if anyone wants to see them.

By my understanding, bronze tag badges are [awarded when](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/68395#68395):

- The user has 100 points (upvotes minus downvotes) on answers under this tag (check)
- On at least 20 questions (check)
- Only non-community-wiki, non-deleted answers are considered

I think I passed the second of the first two requirements maybe a week ago (probably the points boundary was passed second, I wasn't really watching, I know it was close a few weeks back).

"Community-wiki" I hear you thinking. I know I did. But I checked my answers on the tag - I can't find *any* CW questions or answers among the ones I have answers on, but in any case, even if I missed some, I have been through one by one and I counted over 100 points and over 20 answers without CW or deletion.

(At least [one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51718/assessing-approximate-distribution-of-data-based-on-histogram/51753#51753) of my answers became CW at one point - I've edited and updated enough times to trigger CW - but that CW was removed on request long ago. I wouldn't think that this would affect the badge though.)

* I note when checking that first link in my question that this page and other badge-related pages have recently changed... but I doubt that could affect anything either.

Edit: I note that only 18 of my [answers there](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a805%20[histogram]) have positive points... but again, I don't think it could be that.

I'm not all that worried about the badge, but I'm at a loss to explain what the cause of it is (and if it happens to me for whatever reason, presumably it will occur again, so in that broad sense it's certainly a concern).

I've tried searching meta on SO as well as here but I can't figure out what the issue is.

Did I miss something? Or is there perhaps a bug of some kind?

Comment: If you hover over tags it does say 100 upvotes for at least 20 answers in the tool tip (ambiguous still I know). I went through and upvoted a few of your zero answers (all deserve it!), so that should not be a problem. I thought this wasn't awarded immediately either, but I can't find any meta threads to confirm this. So maybe wait a few days and then see if you still haven't been awarded.

Comment: From your description, it seems like you may have gone through all of your answers 1 by 1. If so, there's an easier way: Go to your user page & in the little tags section mouseover the number (`119`) to the left of the tag. A flag will pop up that says the # of non-cw questions w/ total score & the # of non-cw answers w/ total score.

Comment: @gung thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That one puzzled me several times, too, on another site.  It turns out there is an additional requirement over which you have little control: a tag has to appear in at least 100 threads in order to qualify for badges.  Presently, [histogram](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/histogram) has been used only 93 times.  Have patience.

Comment: +1, that answers something that puzzled me the other day. I often read down the badges on the main page to check out any nice questions / answers, etc., I may have missed, & I noticed a couple of days ago that @chl got the badge for `psychometrics`. I thought that was weird, so I went to his page & his score is 215 on 31 questions. I just checked & it seems that we just went over 100 tagged threads.

Comment: Thanks very much, puzzle solved. I'm content now; I am sure this question will arise again from others over time, and now I'll know what to say about it.

Comment: @gung that's a neat idea; I hadn't thought of that as a strategy for finding good questions and answers.

Comment: Embarrassingly, the meta post I linked to with the information on the bronze badge requirements *has* this information -- just not listed under the requirements for the bronze badge ... but it's right above the bit I referred to. How could I miss it? <Insert sheepish grin>